# How do you disable keyboards (or lock the video player) in Kodi?

Tags: pi-3, kodi, keyboard

Simple question: how do you disable all keyboards in Kodi? I tried looking for the keymaps folder so I can edit the keyboards.xml file but can't seem to find it. If there is a way to master lock (using a PIN) the video player before someone can use the media controls, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a keyboard, you could simply unbind all the keyboard commands.  In order to do this, you need this addon:

http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Keymap_Editor

While this might not be the most elegant way to do this, I think it would work.

Comment: How would you unbind the keyboard commands using this addon? The "remove" buttons won't do anything for me.

Comment: Press a key on your keyboard that Kodi can't recognize (i.e scroll lock or some other function)

Comment: I managed to disable most of the keys but I can't disable the media keys on keyboards because they are tied to my remote controller.